# php ajax autocomplete - exact matches are missing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I have a simple PHP/MySQL/Ajax Autocomplete app, which is showing available addresses while the user is typing (as google maps does).

Application works and shows the results
[image]

Once the user starts adding property number, results are changing (e.g. 260 and 269 are gone)
[image]

and if the user add additional number, there is only 1 result (numbers 270-277 are gone)
[image]

Query in PMA (records exists)
[image]

and here is my code for getting the data from DB

```
        $search_param = "%{$this->text}%";

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE address like ?) AS x LIMIT 5,5';

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$search_param);
        $stmt->execute();
```

and then save the result in array

```
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                extract($row);
                $address_item = array(
                    'address' => $address
                );

            //Push the data
            array_push($address_arr['data'], $address_item);

            }
```

Comment: Please remove limit condition after checking result

Comment: Note that SQL resultsets are **orderless** by definition meaning `LIMIT 5,5` without a deterministic `ORDER BY` condition is pretty much **meaningless**.. As pagination / batch processing in SQL always requires a deterministic sort no exceptions..

Comment: ... also you might want to consider using a `FULLTEXT` index and `WHERE MATCH (...) AGAINST(....)` instead as `WHERE LIKE '%..%'` can never use a index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE address like ?) AS x LIMIT 0,5';
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers